# Android studio ZXing library scan barcode and get the data into a custom class

Tags: android-studio, zxing

So i have my custom class with its own properties:

> public class PlayerClass {
>
> public String name;
>
> public int age;
>
> public String id;
>
> public String teamTag;

and i want to scan a barcode and create a player from the barcode info.

so i scan the barcode

```
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

and then i get the info

> String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

So how do i get the info from the scan into a PlayerClass in order to fill its properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way is to create the barcode such that it has information stored in the format:

> name|age|id|teamTag

So now when you get the scanned content in scanContent String you will have this info.

In your Class you can make constructor like:

```
PlayerClass(String content){
     String part[] = content.split("|");
     name = part[0];
     age = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
     id = part[2];
     teamTag = part[3];
}
```